# How to update .bashrc with PATH

Tags: rhel, path, bashrc

I have installed a new JRE on my RedHat linux system.

```
lsb_release -i -r
Distributor ID: CentOS
Release:    6.5
```

I have updated the symbolic links pointing to the desired Java installation:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jul 21 16:27 /usr/bin/java -> /usr/java/jre1.8.0_51

ls -l /usr/java/latest
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jul 21 15:34 /usr/java/latest -> /usr/java/jre1.8.0_51


ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 20 Jul 21 17:42 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/java/glassfish4
```

But, now when I run:

```
java -version
-bash: java: command not found
```

Environment variables:

```
env
...
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
...
```

So I added the following line to .bashrc:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME"
```

But still get:

```
java -version
-bash: java: command not found
```

**Resolved - correct line in bashrc:**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/
```

I don't know why, but using the environment variable pointing to symbolic link `export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME"` does not work, even though it's correctly resolving:

```
ls -l /usr/java/latest
    lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 21 Jul 21 15:34 /usr/java/latest -> /usr/java/jre1.8.0_51
```

**I would really like to understand why?**

Comment: @Christopher -  That resolves the exception, but still getting `-bash: java: command not found` after logging out/in again

Comment: @Christopher -  There is a symbolic link in the jre1.8.0_51 directory that points to the bin directory `java -> /usr/bin/java`  that was part of the installation (I did not create it).  I don't know the answer to your question:   
`Is this applicable on your RHEL system? (/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it didn't work with `$JAVA_HOME` is that `$JAVA_HOME` isn't the same thing as `$JAVA_HOME/bin`. Your binaries (`java`, `javac`, `javaws`, etc) are all found in the `bin` directory inside your `$JAVA_HOME`, not in the `$JAVA_HOME` itself.

The working line in your question points towards `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_51/bin`; the `JAVA_HOME` variable points towards `/usr/java/latest`, which is a symlink to `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_51`. That's clearly not the same place.

If you use

```
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

it will work.

Comment: Neither resolve my issue.